# Angular form validation won't trigger

Tags: angularjs

I'm trying to get the form validation on -URL REMOVED- to trigger when I submit and it's not.  I believe I have things setup correctly but am clearly missing something.

Comment: Are you trying to run actual validations with callbacks etc, or just prevent the form from being submitted with invalid fields/mark invalid fields red?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like angularjs requires a model bound on an input to use the validation.

See http://jsfiddle.net/adamdbradley/Qdk5M/

Try removing ng-model="email", run, and you'll notice the validation no longer works.

```
<input type="email" id="inputEmail" placeholder="Email" ng-model="email" required>
```

vs

```
<input type="email" id="inputEmail" placeholder="Email"  required>
```

Comment: I'm trying to use Angular's validation.  My understanding is that in order to use Angular's and not the HTML5 validation I need the attribute `novalidate`

Comment: Interesting, I've never used that attribute on my angular forms, but I see that in the docs.